# SQL Server service could not be run after installing Microsoft security essentials

Tags: services, sql-server-2008

I had a SQL server 2008 (Express edition) installation in my Windows 7 (64 bit) and it was working fine. Couple of days back,i installed Microsoft Security Essentials and now when i try  to open my SQL management studio,it didnt work.So i went to services and found that it is Disabled.I changed it to "Automatic" and and click on the "Start" button to start the service.
I am getting the following error then

[image]

I checked the event log and found this.

[image]

Any thoughts how to get rid of this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to corruption of master database file. Try repairing the SQL Express installation and see if that helps.

Comment: that will take my databases away rite ? i dont want to do that

Comment: If your master database is corrupt, you're already out of luck. Best go back to a backup of your database and restore that.

Comment: Also, it's unlikely that the Security Essentials is the cause of the problem. It's more likely coincidental.

Comment: Just copy over the ldf and mdf file of your database and then do a repair. I don't think a repair will destroy your database. All you may have to do is re-attach your databases.